# Android : where should widget fonts be set?

Tags: android

Am trying to set font sizes to text programmatically in an Android widget. If I set them in `onEnabled()`, it's not working. I hate to set in `onUpdate()` because unnecessarily, it will be called each time. Any help please?

Comment: Try to set in onCreate()

Comment: @AnandSavjani widgets don't have onCreate() I believe

Comment: unfortunately all changes to the widget UI should be done in the onUpdate() method